# getting error while running phpunit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I made one file in ryapi folder connection.php in this file i putted this code :

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
          array(0, 0, 0),
          array(0, 1, 1),
          array(1, 0, 1),
          array(1, 1, 3)
        );
    }
}
?>
```

when i running this test by following getting following error :

```
ubuntu@ip-10-162-234-205:/var/www/ryapi$ phpunit DataTest
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHPUnit 3.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Argument #1 of PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader:checkAndLoad() is no existing fileubuntu@ip-10-162-234-205:/var/www/ryapi$
```

Please suggest What to do ?
Thanks 
**Edit** 
While running command pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit

```
ubuntu@ip-10-162-234-205:/var/www/ryapi$ sudo pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
warning: phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
warning: phpunit/DbUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
warning: phpunit/File_Iterator requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
warning: phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
warning: phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
warning: phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
warning: phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
downloading PHPUnit-3.5.11.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.5.11.tgz (117,869 bytes)
..........................done: 117,869 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit"
downloading DbUnit-1.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download DbUnit-1.0.1.tgz (39,055 bytes)
...done: 39,055 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/DbUnit" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/DbUnit"
downloading File_Iterator-1.2.3.tgz ...
Starting to download File_Iterator-1.2.3.tgz (3,406 bytes)
...done: 3,406 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/File_Iterator" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/File_Iterator"
downloading PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.4.tgz (115,029 bytes)
...done: 115,029 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage"
downloading PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.8.tgz (18,199 bytes)
...done: 18,199 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject"
downloading PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.2.tgz (16,412 bytes)
...done: 16,412 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
downloading PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1.tgz (7,250 bytes)
...done: 7,250 bytes
Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.1 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.0
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
Download of "phpunit/PHP_TokenStream" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHP_TokenStream"
Download failed
install failed
ubuntu@ip-10-162-234-205:/var/www/ryapi$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Deprecation Message

Edit your `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` and change line 1 from "#" to ";"

That should do the trick and get rid of the deprecation message.

### The PHPUnit Error

You are using a very old Version of PHPUnit, I'd suggest upgrading and if it still doesn't work edit your question and I'll get back to you.

`pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit`

### A new pear Version

`pear upgrade pear/pear` and follow the instructions. Or just `pear upgrade pear` if the first one doesn't work out (for whatever reasons)

Comment: @Rahul obvious from the error message, isn't it? Your Pear installation is outdated. Do `pear upgrade-all`. Btw, there is also an [official IRC help channel for Pear in #pear on EFNet`](http://chat.efnet.org/)